# gap in rounded corner border - Internet Explorer specific

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I have an LI tag with a border and border-radius. The tag renders fine in all browsers except IE. I've jumped through all the hoops to get IE into standards mode with the doctype and meta tags, but I'm still getting a small gap in the border, but only on the left hand side. The codepen showing the problem is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufLmn

(That HTML is extracted from the full HTML with IE's developer tools "Element and HTML" thing.

*Update*: It's IE 10, running in a Windows 8 VM. Sorry I forgot to include that bit.

And, turning off the border radius closes the gap entirely. Setting border-radius: 0 also closes the gap. A smaller border shows a smaller gap (noticeable at about 8px).

*Update 2* Here's an image demonstrating the problem:

[image: gap in the border on the left hand side]

Comment: Which version of IE? Also it would be helpful if you just posted a fiddle with a simple example, the outputted source from the dev tool is vast. If you can post the code you wrote it would be easier (css/html)

Comment: can you maybe give us an image? That codepen shows up exactly the same in IE10 and Chrome 30 here. I'm running Windows 8 (not a VM)